# Accessing img src with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
function validate(form) {    
    while ($('#img').attr('src')=="../static/img/placeholder.png") {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

^This code does not work for me. I want to have a form that does not submit while the placeholder img still exists. What mistake am I making with my code?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/{{ curr_user }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate(this);" >

    <div class="submit-image">
        <img id="img" src="../static/img/placeholder.png" onerror="this.src = '../static/img/placeholder.png'" alt="submitted image" />
    </div>
    <span class="input-url text">
        <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="http://" maxlength="320"/>
    </span>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="op" value="Submit" class="form-submit"/
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the contents of $('#img').attr('src')?  Also, why is this in a while loop?

Comment: use an if instead of while.

Comment: That `while` statement should be an `if`. It won't make a difference actually.

Comment: `What mistake am I making with my code?` probably should say `mistakes`.

Comment: Can we see the code that calls your validate function upon submit.

Comment: ^Updated - I had not displayed my form declaration code.

Comment: Thanks, please have a look at my answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your current example, this should be enough:

```
function validate() {    
    return $('#img').attr('src') != '../static/img/placeholder.png';
}

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  return validate();
});
```

See a more detailed example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ENnLC/

Comment: This did not work - when I used the alert function to check it - I got a message saying that it was Undefined

Comment: alert($('#img').attr('src'));

Comment: I have my javascript in a separate file - is that why it doesn't work I do import the file though.

Comment: I think it's because my submit button changes the image and then submits it so there's a problem with my code - this code is right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a Regex to confirm that src contains the placeholder.png

```
if( ( /placeholder\.png$/.test( $('#img').attr('src') ) ) {
        return false;
}
```

Just one other point. Your code here

```
<img id="img" src="../static/img/placeholder.png" onerror="this.src = '../static/img/placeholder.png'" alt="submitted image" />
```

You are loading the same image on the onerror event which will attempt to load the same image and trigger the onerror event again and lead you to enter an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't think it creates an infinite loop. The placeholder is just kept when an incorrect url is inputted by the user. Basically, I want the form to not submit - until a proper image takes the place of the placeholder.

Comment: Also, I am new to JS - coming from a Python bckgrd. Why is while not recommended for JS?

Comment: `while` is normally used when you want to loop through a conditional statement. However your code only requires you to execute your statement `return false;` once and for that an `if` statement is enough.